# How to start Chromium Edge selenium webdriver in application mode using powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I would like to start the Chromium Edge selenium webdriver in application mode using powershell.

This is how you do it from the powershell command line without the selenium webdriver:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="https://stackoverflow.com"
```

This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't seem to work.
Specifically, the Chromium Edge webdriver window starts up, but not in application mode.

```
$optionSettings =  @{
   BrowserName = ''
   BinaryLocation = $pathToDriver
}
$options = New-Object -TypeName OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions -Property $optionSettings
$options.addArgument("app='https://stackoverflow.com'")
$service = [OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService]::CreateDefaultService($pathToDriver, 'msedgedriver.exe')
$driver = New-Object -TypeName OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver -ArgumentList $service,$options
```

I've also tried substituting the following for the addArgument:

```
$options.addArgument("app=https://stackoverflow.com")
$options.addArgument("--app='https://stackoverflow.com'")
$options.addArgument("--app=https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you need to start Chromium Edge via Webdriver, you need to use `EdgeDriver` instead of ChromeDriver. Secondly, you need to use `Selenium 4` webdriver or above.

Here is a simple demo, and it works well:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("E:\Selenium\WebDriver.dll")

$options = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions
$options.addArguments("--app=https://stackoverflow.com")
#$options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = $True

$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\",$options)

#$driver.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

**Note:** Modify the path parameters according to your own situation.

Comment: It is working now. I used the latest Selenium 4 Webdriver (I was using 3.14.0, which is the stable version) with the parameters specified above.